# pysam or piping samtools view to a python script

Tags: python, sam, samtools, pysam

Is it faster to use the PySam package to run a python script on a bam

```
for read in samfile.fetch('chr1', 100, 120):
 print read
```

compared to using a pipe and reading line by line from stdin in a python script.

`samtools view example.bam | python script.py.`

```
for line in tqdm(sys.stdin, total=number_of_lines)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit hard to say with certainty, though I would suspect that offloading the BAM decompression by using a pipe will be very slightly faster. Note that decompressing and parsing the BAM file will not be the bottleneck in your processing, rather the python script itself will be.